# How to click on Javascript button in Selenium with no ID (Java)?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I'm setting up a program in Java with Selenium.

At the start of the program, a Chrome extension I'm using with the program loads up with the Chrome instance.

Chrome then navigates to that page, selects all the boxes, and is supposed to click a button on the page that appears because of the extension.

So I am trying to click that button, but it's a Javascript button that comes on the page through the extension. There is no ID that I can use explicitly though.

When I inspect the element, all I see is this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="selected button-task" 
style="width: 140px; margin-left: 5px; height: 23px;">
<img src="websiteimage.png here" width="20px">Selected Task</a>
```

Unlike the other stuff I can click on, there is no type (checkboxes, button, etc) or a specific ID I can seek out. But it is important I click this button. What should I do?

I get this error when I use this:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: 
Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //a[contains@class,'selected'] and contains(@class, 'repost-selected button-task') and contains(text(), 'Repost Selected') because of the following error:

SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': 
The string '//a[contains@class,'selected'] and contains(@class, 'repost-selected button-task') and contains(text(), 'Repost Selected')' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to solve it:

```
WebElement extensionBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[normalize-space()='Selected Task']"));

Actions actionsTwo = new Actions(driver);
JavascriptExecutor jseTwo = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
actionsTwo.moveToElement(extensionBox).click();
jseTwo.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", extensionBox);
```

The other answers weren't working because they either wouldn't find the object on the page, or would give compile errors

Answer (score 1):

> But it is important I click this button. What should I do?

You can click this button using following approaches :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
```

- using `By.cssSelector()` :-

  ```
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a.selected.button-task"))).click();
  ```
- using `By.linkText()` :-

  ```
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Selected Task"))).click();
  ```
- using `By.partialLinkText()` :-

  ```
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.partialLinkText("Selected Task"))).click();
  ```
- using `By.xpath()` :-

  ```
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//a[normalize-space()='Selected Task']"))).click();
  ```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! Unfortunately when I write: WebDriverWait wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10), it gives me back a syntax error, saying: "The method WebDriverWait(ChromeDriver, int) is undefined for the type AutomateProgram." This is weird b/c I imported WebDriverWait and everything. Any ideas?

Comment: @user3196126 It shouldn't `ChromeDriver`, you need to pass reference variable of this which you have initiated earlier. Some like as `ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();WebDriverWait(driver, 10)`

Comment: Oh no, I did exactly that, you can see what I did in my screenshot here. I blurred out some of the confidential details, but everything relevant is there: http://i.imgur.com/kA6WhbY.png

Comment: @user3196126 Ah, sorry it should be `new WebDriverWait(driver,10);`

Comment: Thanks for the response, but one last error: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (295, 564). Other element would receive the click: <div class="description-column table-cell">...</div>. So basically it's not being directed to the right point to click. I had a similar error in my code before and used Javascriptexecutor (see screenshot) but I'm not sure how to integrate WebDriverWait with JavascriptExecutor to fix things. If you could help me out, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: @user3196126 Just simply try as `((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a.selected.button-task"))))` or with other locator suggested. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains@class,'selected'] and contains(@class, 'button-task') and contains(text(), 'Selected Task')")).click()
```

Comment: Hi, this gives me back an error, I put it in the original post so you can see it, thanks